# Does HTML5 support HTTP Psuedostreaming of video?

Tags: html, video-streaming, jwplayer, http-streaming

Can I click on some time and eventhough the video is not downlaoded till that time and the video starts playing from the time I clicked?
If yes, what would be a better option for viewing streamed video- HTML5 or flash player like JW player? WHich one will have less lag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this with Firefox and Firebug and while you can "seek" to a point in the video without having to watch video preceding the point you wish to seek, this still causes the entire video file to download.

Indeed, each time you seek in Firefox 4, the entire video downloads.

This may change and improve as HTML 5 video implementations become more mature and may differ based on the actual browser being used.

More information on the test here:

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201106/Blog/HTML-5-Video-In-Real-Life/

Comment: so does the user has to wait for the video to download before it is downloaded till that time? Also, is this feature supported by all browsers?

Comment: The user has to wait until sufficient video has been downloaded for the location they selected, so if they select near the end, very nearly the whole video. I've updated the article with some test results from various browsers.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 browsers generally don't support this, however I believe the video tag in Safari will work with the Apple HTTP Streaming format for this functionality. For something that works across all browsers, Flash Player can do it using either RTMP streaming or HTTP Streaming (either with our without OSMF to support this). Probably the easiest place to start is with OSMF, which supports both RTMP and HTTP streaming of video.